# How can I insert stress symbols above word syllables?

Tags: symbols, overset, phonetic

Is it possible to create something like this in LaTeX?

[image]

I need those dots above the unstressed and stressed syllables. In LibreOffice, I created a table with hidden borders. Each word and symbol is a separate table cell. I was wondering if there is a different way to re-create this in LaTeX.

Comment: Have you checked out the `metrix` package? https://www.ctan.org/pkg/metrix Might be all you need.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to LaTeX and didn't know about that. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I'm curious if the `metrix` package allows me to add those custom dot symbols that I use as they are not part of the default symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simplified `metrix` feature is implemented here. All used tools are only TeX primitives or plain TeX macros.

```
\def\replspace #1 #2{\ifx#2\end
   \else\space #1-\expandafter\replspace\expandafter#2\fi}
\long\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\begingroup\toks0={\endgroup#2}\toks1={\endgroup#3}%
   \let\tmp= #1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\metrix #1#2{\leavevmode \def\tmpa{#1}%
   \edef\tmpb{\replspace #2 \end}\expandafter\meA\tmpb\end}
\def\meA #1#2-{\meB{#1#2}\isnextchar{ }{ \meA}{\isnextchar\end{\meE}{\meA}}}
\def\meB#1{\expandafter\nextA\tmpa\relax\end
   \ifx\next*\meC{$\bullet$}{\bf #1}\fi
   \ifx\next.\meC{$\cdot$}{#1}\fi
}
\def\nextA #1#2\end{\let\next=#1\def\tmpa{#2}}
\def\meC#1#2{\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr#1\cr#2\cr}}}
\def\meE{\let\next=}


\metrix { .    *  *  .  .  .  .     .  *  *  . }
        {flos ve-te-ris vi-ni meis na-ri-bus ob}

\bigskip

\metrix { .   .    *  .   *    .  .  *   . }
        {Can you come in-side for a min-ute}?


\bye
```

Comment: Your code looks a little bit complicated. I tried the `metrix` package and it works but I don't like the default symbols. I was wondering if those can be replaced to use the bullets. I like the `\metrics { .    *  *  .  .  .  .     .  *  *  . }
         {flos ve-te-ris vi-ni meis na-ri-bus ob}` synthax, though.

Comment: Please, look into `metrix.sty` and compare the code here with my code. IMHO, the code inside `metrix.sty` is much more complicated.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Maybe, my code seems to you as complicated because it is impossible to run it in LaTeX (because of `\replstring`). OK, I added definition of special `\replspace` to my example. Now, my code is based only on TeX primitives and simple plain TeX macros, so it can be processed in LaTeX too.

Comment: I like your approach, especially the `\metrix` tag looks great because even if I don't have LaTeX installed and just look at the document with a text editor the content in `\metrix` makes a lot of sense. So, you are using tex-metrix, right? The only thing I dislike are the default characters in it. I checked its PDF documentation and haven't found a way to change those.

Comment: @ZoltanKing You can replace default characters to something else. This is plain TeX approach: you see simple macro, you see `\bullet` in it and you can replace it by somewhat else if you want. You need not any parameters, only replace the simple macro by your version of the macro. This approach is much more powerful than doing complicated macros with dozens of parameters documented in a large documentation, but maybe users will want somewhat not provided by all these parameters.

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but I'm getting these errors: https://ibb.co/QYmyMqz

Comment: The picture of errors doesn't show errors themself, for example what control sequence is undefined. Maybe you use LaTeX incorrectly, I don't se `\documentclass` for example. Am I am not able to work with a tool which does not show full errors.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the `\def\isnextchar`. Can you please update your example?

Comment: OK, I added \isnextchar definition now. Thank you for your notice.

Answer (score 8):

With a handier markup: `\?{...}` means nontonic syllable, `\?*{...}` means a tonic one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?

\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also adjust the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?

\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?

\end{document}
```

[image]

For Charis SIL (and XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?

\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how to use the phrases in context. Please, provide yourself the phonetic transcriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\bulletfont}{DejaVu Serif}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \bulletfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
    \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
  \end{tabular}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\phrase}{mm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}
  \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\\#2\end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}
}

\begin{document}

Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
in context; sorry, but I'm not going to look for those IPA symbols.

\phrase{\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?}
  {Abcdefghijk}

\phrase{\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?}
  {Abcdefghijk}

Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
in context; sorry, but I'm not going to look for those IPA symbols.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. This is very cool. Can I insert xelatex with your code as well? I mean I would like to type out the IPA symbols without any special Latex flag and XeLaTeX supports that because I specify the `Charis SIL` or `DejaVu Sans Mono` fonts which contain the IPA characters.

Comment: @ZoltanKing I added the change.

Comment: Thank you. If I want some spacing between the phrases do I need to use `\bigskip` ? Do you have an idea why the dots are a little bit smaller when using `Chris SIL`?

Comment: @ZoltanKing It seems that the bold middle dot in Charis SIL is the same as in the regular font; you might use a different font for those glyphs where the glyphs are distinct. For the spacing around, you might want a command that does the job, taking as first argument the syllable divisions and second argument the IPA, so you can add space above or below as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I like your method. Is it possible to add a little bit of vertical space between the phrase and the phonetic transcription? Just a very little, 0.2em or something like that. Also, is it possible to number the phrases, is there a package for that? Check out this image https://ibb.co/hd9qjrB

Comment: @ZoltanKing Change `#1\\#2` into `#1\\[0.5ex]#2` or what you deem to be the right space. About numbering, you're asking too much in comments.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to know if there is a package for numbering. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I think the stackengine should be able to do that nicely:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Make sure to use a font that supports 
% the bullets you need:

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}         

\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}

\begin{document}

\stackon{Can}{•} \stackon{you}{•} \stackon{come}{●}
\stackon{in}{•}\stackon{side}{•} \stackon{for}{•} 
\stackon{a}{•} \stackon{min}{●}\stackon{ute?}{•}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks great. Would it be possible to make it without repeating the word `\stackon` so many times? Considering I will have many phrases. Also what can I do to make some spacing between the phrases? I mean vertical space between them.

Comment: @egreg gave you a handy alternative, using `\?` and `\*?` … It's not going to get shorter than a one-letter command and its starred variant. `\stackon` also allows you define the height of the whole stack, so try something like `\stackon[5mm]{…}`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. like SebGlav's method with stackon and tikz because it doesn't need to repeat the dot symbols, and the symbols are not font dependent. Charis SIL, the font I use, doesn't have big dots.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't feel using luatex, here's a simple way to do it with Ti*k*Z:

[image: stack stress signs]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}         

\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}

\newcommand{\lstress}[1]
    {%
    \stackon{#1}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \fill[opacity=0] circle (0.5ex);
            \fill circle (0.25ex);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }%
    }
\newcommand{\hstress}[1]
    {%
    \stackon{\bfseries{#1}}{\tikz \fill circle (0.5ex);}%
    }
    
\begin{document}
        
    \lstress{Can} \lstress{you} \hstress{come} \lstress{in}\hstress{side}?
\end{document}
```

Note that % are important to avoid unwanted spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. I would like to use XeLaTeX because I want to type out the IPA characters directly in the document.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome. I don't see what prevents you from using either one solution or the other but you're the OP. Feel free to vote up anyway if you think the answer is a correct one ;)

Comment: Can I make use of the Charis SIL fonts? I mean to have the IPA and text in Charis SIL but the stress dots to stay like yours since the Charis doesn't have good looking dots. Also can I add some spacing between the phrases?

Comment: The method presented above is not font dependent, you can use whichever you want. Make your own tries and come back to ask another question if needed (by creating another thread).