# How to number each phrase and make the text wrap for longer phrases?

Tags: phonetic

I got some help [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634437/how-can-i-insert-stress-symbols-above-word-syllables) on the TEX page and with the help of this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\bulletfont}{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
        \bulletfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
    \end{tabular}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\phrase}{mm}{%
    \par\addvspace{4ex}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\\[0.2ex]#2\end{tabular}%
    \par\addvspace{4ex}
}

\begin{document}
    
    Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
    in context.
    
    \phrase{\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?}
    {dʊ jʊ ˈwɑnt səm ˈbrɛk fəst? ↗}
    
    \phrase{\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?}
    {kæn jʊ ˈkʌm‿ɪnˈsaɪd fər‿ə ˈmɪn ɪt? ↗}
    
    
    \phrase{\?{I'm} \?*{sor}\?{ry} \?{I} \?*{have}\?{n't} \?*{had} \?{the} \?*{chance} \?{to} \?*{call} \?{you} \?*{back.} \?{I'm} \?*{sor}\?{ry} \?{I} \?*{have}\?{n't} \?*{had} \?{the} \?*{chance} \?{to} \?*{call} \?{you} \?*{back.}}
    {(phonetic transcription here)}
    
    Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
    in context.
    
\end{document}
```

I can produce something like this:

[image]

Things are looking fine for shorter phrases but when the phrase is too long it runs out of the page. Would it be possible to make it wrap? even if manually? The case when I will need to deal with longer phrases is rare, probably 1 in 200, but it can happen and I don't want the phrase to run out of the page.

Also, would it be possible to number the phrases, keeping them at the same indentation level? like so:

```
     x x x x x x
  1. Phrase phrase
     Phonetic transcription

     x x x x x x
 10. Phrase
     Phonetic transcription

     x x x x x x
100. Phrase
     Phonetic transcription
```

Here's a simpler version:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{geometry}

\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in}   

\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}

\newcommand{\lstress}[1]
{%
    \stackon{#1}{*}%
}%

\begin{document}
    \lstress{First  Sentence} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second \lstress{First} Second
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a link to your first question.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the number with enumerate.  You can wrap the text by replacing the outer tabular with a `\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{...}`.  The (default) space for the number is `\labelwidth - \labelsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}% Sorry, but I hate having to mess with fonts.
%\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
%\newfontfamily{\bulletfont}{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.65in, showframe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{sm}{%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
        %\bulletfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{\bfseries}#2
    \end{tabular}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\phrase}{mm}{%
    %\par\addvspace{4ex}
    \noindent\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{#1\\[0.2ex]#2}%
    %\par\addvspace{4ex}
}

\begin{document}
    
    Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
    in context.
    
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \phrase{\?{Do} \?{you} \?*{want} \?{some} \?*{break}\?{fast}?}
    {dʊ jʊ ˈwɑnt səm ˈbrɛk fəst? ↗}
    
    \item \phrase{\?{Can} \?{you} \?*{come} \?{in}\?*{side} \?{for} \?{a} \?*{min}\?{ute}?}
    {kæn jʊ ˈkʌm‿ɪnˈsaɪd fər‿ə ˈmɪn ɪt? ↗}
    
    \setcounter{enumi}{99}%  
    \item \phrase{\?{I'm} \?*{sor}\?{ry} \?{I} \?*{have}\?{n't} \?*{had} \?{the} \?*{chance} \?{to} \?*{call} \?{you} \?*{back.}
      \?{I'm} \?*{sor}\?{ry} \?{I} \?*{have}\?{n't} \?*{had} \?{the} \?*{chance} \?{to} \?*{call} \?{you} \?*{back.}}%
    {(phonetic transcription here)}
    \end{enumerate}
    
    Some explanatory text without any real meaning, just to show the phrases
    in context.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. It works. Thank you so much. Everything looks great. I still have the Charis font enabled but it doesn't seem to have a negative impact on anything. 

I was wondering if there is a way to add just a little bit of space between the wrapped line. If not, then it's not a big deal. Check out https://ibb.co/F6Vs2BJ Vertical space between the phonetic transcription is not important.

Comment: I tried making the large bullets larger by adding `\bulletfont\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\Large \textbullet}{\textbf{\textperiodcentered}}\\[-0.5ex]` and I like it better but the smaller bullets don't align vertically with the larger ones. The smaller bullets a little bit lower. https://ibb.co/WnZ0cdH

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't use fancy fonts, I just don't want to deal with them while debugging.  See `\raisebox` to adjust individual symbols.

Comment: I need some vertical spacing between the wrapped lines, not the individual symbols. The font is used for the IPA characters in XeLaTeX.

Comment: I updated my post at the bottom with a simpler version. I still need that vertical space between the wrapped lines.

Comment: For wrapped lines you need to temporarily increase \baselineskip (or possibly \baselinestretch).  For specific lines, you can use \vskip, \vspace or \addvspace.  Note that \item adds \itemsep.

Comment: I found this which solves the issue `\addstackgap[10pt]{\stackon{#1}{•}}`