# How to make certain words in a phrase bold using this metrix-like approach?

Tags: symbols, overset, phonetic

I have a tex file with English phrases along with their phonetic transcription:

```
\phrase
{ *     *    *    .   }
{Whoa, what hap-pened?}
{ˈwoʊ, ˈwʌt̚ ˈhæp ənd?}

\phrase
{ *  .  .  *   .   *   *   }
{May-be a lit-tle too much.}
{ˈmeɪ biʸə ˈlɪd l ˈtu ˈmʌtʃ.}
```

The generated output looks like so:

[image]

I like this `metrix`-like approach because I don't need to fill my phrases with a lot of `\textbf{word}` commands, so my phrases look cleaner.

This metrix code was provided to me by Petr Olsak, RNDr @wipet https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/634483/263939

```
\def\stressed#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr\scalebox{1.1}{\raisebox{-0.28ex}{$\bullet$}}\cr\bf#1\cr}}}
\def\unstressed#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr$\ssize\bullet$\cr#1\cr}}}
\let\ssize=\scriptscriptstyle

\def\replspace #1 #2{\space #1-%
    \ifx#2\end \else \expandafter\replspace\expandafter#2\fi}
\def\metrix #1#2{\leavevmode \def\tmpa{#1}%
    \edef\tmpb{\replspace #2 \end}\expandafter\meA\tmpb\end}
\def\meA #1#2-{\meB{#1#2}\isnextchar{ }{ \meA}{\isnextchar\end{\meE}{\meA}}}
\def\meB#1{\expandafter\nextA\tmpa\relax\end
\ifx\next*\stressed{#1}\fi
\ifx\next.\unstressed{#1}\fi
}
\def\nextA #1#2\end{\let\next=#1\def\tmpa{#2}}
\def\meE{\let\next=}

\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\begingroup\toks0={\endgroup#2}\toks1={\endgroup#3}%
\let\tmp= #1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\phrase#1#2#3{\metrix{#1}{#2}\vskip-0.5ex\relax #3\vskip5ex\relax}
```

I realized that I don't need the stress dots (large and small dots) in the generated PDF, but they would be okay to stay in the tex file as they're now. However, I would like the words to remain bold in the generated PDF based on where I put the star in the tex file.

Would someone be able to modify Petr Olsak's code, or maybe he will see this post. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Instead of just a code snippet, please provide a small working example of code (`\documentclass...\end{document}`), for us to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine `\stressed` and `\unstressed` as shown.

The OP did not suggest a font supporting these symbols, but I found `Linux Libertine O`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\def\stressed#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr\scalebox{1.1}{\raisebox{-0.28ex}{$\bullet$}}\cr\bf#1\cr}}}
%\def\unstressed#1{\leavevmode\vbox{\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\cr$\ssize\bullet$\cr#1\cr}}}
\def\stressed#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\unstressed#1{#1}
\let\ssize=\scriptscriptstyle

\def\replspace #1 #2{\space #1-%
    \ifx#2\end \else \expandafter\replspace\expandafter#2\fi}
\def\metrix #1#2{\leavevmode \def\tmpa{#1}%
    \edef\tmpb{\replspace #2 \end}\expandafter\meA\tmpb\end}
\def\meA #1#2-{\meB{#1#2}\isnextchar{ }{ \meA}{\isnextchar\end{\meE}{\meA}}}
\def\meB#1{\expandafter\nextA\tmpa\relax\end
\ifx\next*\stressed{#1}\fi
\ifx\next.\unstressed{#1}\fi
}
\def\nextA #1#2\end{\let\next=#1\def\tmpa{#2}}
\def\meE{\let\next=}

\def\isnextchar#1#2#3{\begingroup\toks0={\endgroup#2}\toks1={\endgroup#3}%
\let\tmp= #1\futurelet\next\isnextcharA
}
\def\isnextcharA{\the\toks\ifx\tmp\next0\else1\fi\space}

\def\phrase#1#2#3{\metrix{#1}{#2}\vskip-0.5ex\relax #3\vskip5ex\relax}\begin{document}

\phrase
{ *     *    *    .   }
{Whoa, what hap-pened?}
{ˈwoʊ, ˈwʌt̚ ˈhæp ənd?}

\phrase
{ *  .  .  *   .   *   *   }
{May-be a lit-tle too much.}
{ˈmeɪ biʸə ˈlɪd l ˈtu ˈmʌtʃ.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help so much.